# Python 3.X make setup for executable

Tags: python-3.x, installation

I am developing a pentest framework (https://github.com/LuanDevecchi/PostBuilder) and would like it to be more complex, which has a setup that installs an executable in usr/bin

How could I do a setup that would install the .py script in a usr/bin executable form? with a symlink? if so, how to create a symlink in Setup?

For example, the script name is post_builder.py, how could I run it globally only with post_builder? I already did this using chmod + x in the file and saving it without the .py extension, but how do I do this in setup?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) is designed to do.  Admittedly, it's rather clumsy, but writing a good `setup.py` file (pay special attention to [script creation](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation)) will automate this process and keep it platform agnostic (if that matters to you).

There are [lots](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#packaging-your-project) [of](http://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) [guides](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/) to python package creation, which is a good thing as it's one of python's weakest points.